# Loading image from url in jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-image, jlabel

i'm trying to set an img as background into a Jlabel (or a JScrollPanel) and i recieve a exception that i am unable to resolve. My code is the following:

```
public void cargaImagen(String dir){

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(dir);

        //Image image = ImageIO.read(dir);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(dir, ""); 
        this.Jlabel_imagen.setIcon(icon);


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.Jlabel_imagen.updateUI();
}
```

The exception that I get is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at vista.ParteTres.cargaImagen(ParteTres.java:225)

The line 225 is:   `this.Jlabel_imagen.setIcon(icon);`

Comment: `Jlabel_imagen` is null?

Comment: `//Image image = ImageIO.read(dir);` That was good approach

Comment: Null pointer exception means that something is null and is being used in an improper way. Make sure that the icon is being read properly? Are you passing the correct directory? Is the icon actually there?

Comment: @Kaostias, where did you initialize `Jlabel_imagen`?

Comment: I initialize it in the constructor with the text:  `JLabel Jlabel_imagen = new JLabel("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote line 225 (source of the `NullPointerException`) is:

```
this.Jlabel_imagen.setIcon(icon);
```

`JLabel.setIcon()` accepts `null` (in which case the label will have no icon) which leaves us one option: `this.Jlabel_imagen` is `null`.

Initialize `this.Jlabel_imagen` properly before you call its `setIcon()` method.

And as [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) pointed out a call to `JLabel.updateUI()` is unnecessary, you can remove it.

Comment: I'm sure that will be added to your answer here too, (then) to remove useless code this.Jlabel_imagen.updateUI();

Comment: you can to see that too, added +1

Comment: The weird fact is that I initialize the Jlabel in the constructor. (In fact is generated with WindowBuilder)

Comment: @Kaostias Insert a `System.out.println(this.Jlabel_imagen)` statement just before you call its `setIcon()` and see what it prints.

Comment: Prints null, but I initialize it, I swear... i'm going to look if it looses it's referency

Comment: The problem was obvious. I had a local variable called Jlabel_imagen that was used as the global one. Thank you every one